# jQuery Form Submit Validation Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple validation when a form is submitted to check for the present value of a hidden input, and if that is empty to show an alert:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {
    $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
    return false;
  }
});
```

This works when no selection have been made and prevents the form from being submitted, however if a selection has been made it is not actually submitting the form.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` will stop form from being submitted. Remove it.

Comment: yes. remove event.preventDefault() or add it to last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move **event.preventDefault();** inside your **IF** statement

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
    return false;
  }

});
```

**event.preventDefault()** prevents the default submit behaviour of the form which you put it above this will always execute.

hope that helps .....

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();    // This prevent the form from submitting
  // so remove it and put it inside the condition block 

  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {

    $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
    event.preventDefault();

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {    
  event.preventDefault();    
  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {    
    $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
  }
  else{
    $(this)[0].submit();
  }    
});
```

Make sure there should not be any form element which ***id*** or ***name*** is ***submit***